# Design a navigation bar in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to design a website with a navigation bar like [this](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3751/zcp266bc_png.htm).

I already tried it with the `rotate-tag` from CSS, but it doesn't work.

Is It possible in CSS to create such navigation bar with CSS only or should I use the `background-image` tag ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does not work with `rotate`? Please share the code!

Comment: No one is going to help you if you post such stuff.SO is useful when you stuck in code not for code generation.This kind question can cost your `REPUTATION`

Answer (score 0):

Hacky, but working:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hfbp6vh/)

May need adjustments when you will implementing it on your website.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>About me</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
body {
    background-color: gold;
}

#menu {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -42px;
    left: -800px;
    padding-top: 38px; 
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
    margin-top: 70px;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can tr this.

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFD700;
}
#menu {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  height: 130px;
  left: -800px;
  padding-top: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  text-align: center;
  width: 2000px;
}
#menu ul {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>About me</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```